# Monitoring specific queries in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to monitor specific SQL queries in SQL Server?

For example I would like to get notified somehow when somebody run a specific query against the database. For eg.:

```
Select * 
from table 
where id = 1
```

Thank You!

Comment: If your queries are in SP's you could do a db send mail and email you wheenver the SP is run.  Or you can use Extended Events to do monitoring on the server andi if something is run notify you (though that is not recommended for long, that is a monitoring tool for debugging, figuring out problems, not as a solution for a long term thing.

Comment: This can be done for Update, Delete or Insert. Why do you want this on select?

Comment: SQL Server audit can be used for a lightweight monitoring of selects to specified table, however, it hardly can be possible to add id=1 as a criteria

Comment: In short, no. We need to know what exactly your concerns are to suggest ways in which you can accomplish what you want, since there is no feature in SQL Server that will somehow perform an action when specific query texts are parsed. There are many ways to monitor and audit, though.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can do this. I'd probably start with an audit. Create a server audit.

USE [master]
GO

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE SERVER AUDIT [audit_stackoverflow_question]
TO APPLICATION_LOG
WITH (QUEUE_DELAY = 1000, ON_FAILURE = FAIL_OPERATION)
ALTER SERVER AUDIT [stack] WITH (STATE = OFF)
GO
```

Create a database audit specification.

```
USE [<your_database>]
GO
CREATE DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION [audit_monitor_dbo.table]
FOR SERVER AUDIT [audit_stackoverflow_question]
ADD (SELECT ON OBJECT::[dbo].[table] BY [public])
WITH (STATE = OFF)
GO
```

Enable the audit and database audit specification when you're ready. After that point, activity will be logged (in this case to the application event log):

[image]

You can push activity to a file. Whatever floats your boat. And, after that, you can Powershell out whatever specific activity you want to see.

You can use extended events or traces for this too, but I think an audit is the way to go.

If you're looking after the fact, check the cache tables:

```
SELECT t.[text]
, *
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS p
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(p.plan_handle) AS t
WHERE t.[text] LIKE N'Select%from%table%where%id%'
OPTION (recompile);
```